# How to order x-axis in ggplot by statistically significant differences between two groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am struggling with how to order my x-axis in ggplot by how different two groups are on a variety of measures. Here is a toy dataset of what we can think of as individuals, their political party, and how they scored on several tests to show what I'm talking about

```
sample_df <- data.frame(Party = as.character(c("Republican", "Republican", "Democrat", "Republican", "Democrat", "Democrat", "Democrat", "Republican", "Democrat", "Republican", "Democrat","Republican", "Republican", "Democrat", "Republican", "Democrat", "Democrat", "Democrat", "Republican", "Democrat", "Republican", "Democrat")), 
                        Score = as.numeric(c(34,44,33,112,23,76,12,22,56,54,34,34,44,33,112,23,76,12,22,56,54,34)), 
                        Test = as.character(c("BT", "MS", "PL", "PL", "BT", "MS", "BT","PL", "PL", "BT", "MS","BT", "MS", "PL", "PL", "BT", "MS", "BT","PL", "PL", "BT", "MS")))
```

When I take this dataframe and run this ggplot code:

```
ggplot(sample_df, aes(x=reorder(Test, Score), y=Score, color=Party)) + scale_color_manual(name="Condition", values=c("#CB454A", "#2E74C0"), labels = c("Republican", "Democrat")) + geom_point(stat="summary", fun.y="mean") + geom_errorbar(stat="summary", fun.data="mean_se", fun.args = list(mult = 1.96), width=0) + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=rel(0.5), angle=90))
```

I get this plot:

[image]

I am having trouble running the code in a way that orders the "least significant" differences between Democrats and Republicans to the "most significant". In this particular case, I would want the "BT" test to be the rightmost test here as this is the only "significantly different" test between R's and D's. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Why do you feel you need `as.character` and `as.numeric` in your code?

Comment: `Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: fun.y`, did you transfer that code from `stat_summary(.)`?

Comment: 1) dumb personal habit, 2) yes

Answer (score 0):

library {forcats} has a convenient `fct_reorder` function:

```
library(forcats)

sample_df |>
mutate(Test = fct_reorder(Test, Score, median)) ## |> rest of pipeline
```